# Update to Grub2.x broke Xubuntu 12.04 client in VirtualBox

Tags: grub2, virtualbox

I have VirtualBox-4.1 installed in Ubuntu 10.04 with a `.vdi` running Xubuntu 12.04. Recently, a Grub update for Xubuntu 12.04 to Grub2.x, broke it with the following explanation:

```
error: ELF header smaller than expected
grub rescue> _
```

Is there an easy fix for this? I could reinstall, but I tweaked Xubuntu 12.04 to my liking, and don't want to re-install a new `.vdi`. Unfortunately, I didn't make a snapshot of it.

Google results, have been over my head.

Comment: I never used a VB, so I don't really know if this will work, but have tou tried seimply reinstalling GRUB to mbr? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Answer (score 1):

My first try in situations like this would be Boot-Repair.  You can run it off of a (virtual) LiveCD.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.